# Android Manifest Automatically Generating Invalid Permission

Tags: java, android, xml, error-handling, compiler-errors

I accidentally typed in an invalid permission name in my android manifest and cannot remove it. Here is my manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_CLOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="haveabeer.two.padc.haveabeer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="haveabeer.two.padc.haveabeer.Records"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The problem is that when I highlight and delete the permission and build my app for debugging the permission reappears and prevents my app from building. I cannot edit it, I cannot delete it. If I try to do either it regenerates and says "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited". And yes, I have tried CTRL+Z, I made the error too far back to fix.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I try to do either it regenerates and says "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited".

That is because you are not editing the correct manifest file. You are attempting to edit a generated manifest file, probably because that is the one that Android Studio popped up on your screen. That's poor form on Android Studio's part, and if there isn't a bug report filed on it, I'll get one filed, as I have seen this behavior as well.

Instead, go to the real manifest file (probably in `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` off of your project root) and edit it.

BTW, none of your `<uses-permission>` lines are correct. One cites a group, and the other two cite non-existent permissions.

**UPDATE**: I have filed [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290).

Comment: Thanks it worked. That is a strange issue. What permissions should I use if I am using sharedPreferences to save a few int's?

Comment: @Ethan: You do not need any permissions to work with `SharedPreferences`. Those will be stored in your app's portion of internal storage, and there are no permissions required for working with your app's portion of internal storage.

Comment: Ok thank you! Last question. Everything is working great now!

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the advice. You are trying to edit the generated manifest from **build** folder which gets overwritten everytime you build your project. Navigate to the **source** directory and modify the manifest there.

The path will look similar to this:

[image]