# Android Studio incorrectly reports lack of manifest permission

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 4.2.1
Gradle 6.7.1
Gradle Plugin 4.2.1

From time to time (and unclear what causes this, although I think it might be related to interrupting a full rebuild), Android Studio gets "confused" about what permissions are set in AndroidManifest.xml, and shows errors within source code. Usually this happens on the VIBRATE permission I use, but I have recently started seeing it on NETWORK related permissions, like this:

[image: sample source code with errors]

Even though my manifest has it set:

[image: manifest section]

When this happens, no manner of rebuilds, invalidate cache/restart seems to help, until at some point it generally just "goes away". A build and project run will work, I just continue to see errors in various files which reference permissions that AS thinks I have not granted.

I assume this is some gradle problem? What can I do about it?

Comment: change Gradle Plugin to 4.2.0 maybe help. try with that

Comment: Thanks, but I've just kept up with the various updates as they were released. I had Gradle 4.2.0 prior, and it exhibited the same behavior.

Comment: are you sure that you are editing the correct manifest file? check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790340/android-manifest-automatically-generating-invalid-permission

Comment: Yes - this is the same one that shows up in the Android Studio IDE when viewing the project using the "Android' view, right under App->Manifests. The permissions are there. The weird thing is, when this happens I can sometimes get it to go away by doing a "nonsense edit" in that manifest file (i.e. insert a comment, cut/paste a permission above or below another one, etc.) and then a full rebuild. It's generally the "Vibrate" permission it gets unhappy with, for some reason.

Comment: You can create a new project and use this permissions and codes in that. if didn't work , maybe you should reinstall android studio. it's just my idea. the issue is weird. maybe a better solution exist for that. sorry about that

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea, and did a new install of Android Studio. Didn't help. This issues has come up for me (and others here on SO I have noticed) also in AS 4.1.x as well. Very strange. Thanks for your ideas.